# Conditional Distribution of a Brownian Motion with terminal point in an interval.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathrm{d}X_t=\mu\mathrm{d}t+\sigma \mathrm{d}B_t$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. We know that $X_0=c$ and $X_T\in (a,b)$ where $a,b$ are two known real number and $T$ is a fixed time. I want to find the conditional distribution of $X_t|X_0=c,X_T  \in(a,b)$. Indeed what I am interested is to find the conditional mean and variance. For $t>T$, it is pretty simple, since it is just a truncated normal distribution $X_T|X_T\in(a,b)$ plus an independent increment $X_t-X_T$. However, for $t\in(0,T)$, I cannot figure it out. I guess it could be obtain use some similar techniques as obtaining Brownian bridge with $X_T=x$, however it turns out to be out of my ability.

Comment: If $(p_t)$ denotes the PDF semigroup of $X$, then the conditional distribution you are after has a PDF proportional to the function $g$, where $$g(x)=p_t(c,x)\int_a^bp_{T-t}(x,y)dy$$ Thus, the desired PDF is exactly $g/k$, where $k$ denotes the integral of $g$ on the whole real line, which, by the semigroup property, happens to be $$k=\int_a^bp_T(c,y)dy$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! With the formula you provided I could calculate the desired PDF and moments easily (though the calculation is quite painful).However, I am not familiar with the semigroup property you mention and could not figure out why $g(\cdot)$ is defined this way. Is there any non-math-major-friendly references I can check to have a better understanding of the derivation. (I didn't find it in the books at hand, say Shreve, Oksendal)@Did